# Merge Multiple Data Frames by Row Names

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, reshape

I'm trying to merge multiple data frames by row names.

I know how to do it with two:

```
x = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), row.names = letters[1:3])
y = data.frame(b = c(1,2,3), row.names = letters[1:3])
merge(x,y, by = "row.names")
```

But when I try using the `reshape` package's `merge_all()` I'm getting an error.

```
z = data.frame(c = c(1,2,3), row.names = letters[1:3])
l = list(x,y,z)
merge_all(l, by = "row.names")

Error in -ncol(df) : invalid argument to unary operator
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: put the row names in a column instead and then use `Reduce`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8091303/817778

Comment: e.g. `Reduce(merge, lapply(l, function(x) data.frame(x, rn = row.names(x))))`

Comment: @eddi This is great, very elegant.  Can you add as an answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Merging by `row.names` does weird things - it creates a column called Row.names, which makes subsequent merges hard.

To avoid that issue you can instead create a column with the row names (which is generally a better idea anyway - row names are very limited and hard to manipulate). One way of doing that with the data as given in OP (not the most optimal way, for more optimal and easier ways of dealing with rectangular data I recommend getting to know `data.table` instead):

```
Reduce(merge, lapply(l, function(x) data.frame(x, rn = row.names(x))))
```

Comment: I guess this is the `data.table` equivalent? `Reduce(merge, lapply(l, data.table, keep.rownames = TRUE, key = "rn"))`

Comment: And removing rn column afterwards:    `transform(Reduce(merge, lapply(l, function(x) data.frame(x, rn = row.names(x)))), row.names=rn, rn=NULL)`

Answer (score 2):

maybe there exists a faster version using `do.call` or *`apply`, but this works in your case:

```
x = data.frame(X = c(1,2,3), row.names = letters[1:3])
y = data.frame(Y = c(1,2,3), row.names = letters[1:3])
z = data.frame(Z = c(1,2,3), row.names = letters[1:3])

merge.all <- function(x, ..., by = "row.names") {
  L <- list(...)
  for (i in seq_along(L)) {
    x <- merge(x, L[[i]], by = by)
    rownames(x) <- x$Row.names
    x$Row.names <- NULL
  }
  return(x)
}

merge.all(x,y,z)
```

important may be to define all the parameters (like `by`) in the function `merge.all` you want to forward to `merge` since the whole `...` arguments are used in the list of objects to merge.

Comment: I also like the 2nd comment of @eddi (see question).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `Reduce` and `merge`:

If you put all the data frames into a list, you can then use `grep` and `cbind` to get the data frames with the desired row names.

```
## set up the data
> x <- data.frame(x1 = c(2,4,6), row.names = letters[1:3])
> y <- data.frame(x2 = c(3,6,9), row.names = letters[1:3])
> z <- data.frame(x3 = c(1,2,3), row.names = letters[1:3])
> a <- data.frame(x4 = c(4,6,8), row.names = letters[4:6])
> lst <- list(a, x, y, z)

## combine all the data frames with row names = letters[1:3]
> gg <- grep(paste(letters[1:3], collapse = ""), 
             sapply(lapply(lst, rownames), paste, collapse = ""))
> do.call(cbind, lst[gg])
##   x1 x2 x3
## a  2  3  1
## b  4  6  2
## c  6  9  3
```

Answer (score 0):

A comparable tidyverse solution to the current answer would be:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

reduce(map(l, ~ as_tibble(.x, rownames = "rn")), full_join, by = "rn")
```