# Merging multiple two-column text files into one data frame based on one column

Tags: r, merge, read.table

This question is a follow-up to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201849/merge-join-several-tables-unix-linux), which got negative responses and no answers. So, I'm trying to do this using R.

I have many (more than 30) files like this:

- File1

  ```
  5 A1
  23 A3
  1 B2
  289 BX5
  90 D3
  ```
- File2

  ```
  2 A1
  10 A2
  3 B1
  1 BX4
  90 D3
  24 E0
  ```
- File3

  ```
  4 A0
  11 A2
  1 B1
  2 D3
  ```

And I would like to combine all of them to produce a data frame like this:

```
A0 0 0 4
A1 5 2 0
A2 0 10 11
A3 23 0 0
B1 0 3 1
B2 1 0 0
BX4 0 1 0
BX5 289 0 0
D3 90 90 2
E0 0 24 0
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7739757/4896390), I tried to read two files using read.table while specifying the second column as the row names and then I merged the data frames by row names, like this:

```
> df1 <- read.table("File1", row.names = 2)
> df1
     V1
A1    5
A3   23
B2    1
BX5 289
D3   90
> df2 <- read.table("File2", row.names = 2)
> df2
     V1
A1    2
A2   10
B1    3
BX4   1
D3   90
E0   24
> m1 <- merge(df1, df2, by=0, all=TRUE)
> m1[is.na(m1)] <- 0
> m1
    Row.names V1.x V1.y
1          A1    5    2
2          A2    0   10
3          A3   23    0
4          B1    0    3
5          B2    1    0
6         BX4    0    1
7         BX5  289    0
8          D3   90   90
9          E0    0   24
```

So far so good, but when I tried to merge the resulting data frame to the third one, it doesn't work as I hoped for. And because of that, I'm not sure how I will continue to merge all the 30-something files into one data frame. Previously I thought I would modify the `multmerge` function described [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/merging-multiple-data-files-into-one-data-frame/), but now I'm stuck.

So, would anybody please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I would also really appreciate if anyone could suggest me a better title for this question.

Comment: As this question is marked as duplicate ("has been asked before and already has an answer"), could the people who marked it point out to me where it has been asked? I couldn't find it in Stackoverflow; or I just didn't search hard enough? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617593/merge-multiple-data-frames-by-row-names) for me is different from mine, and I couldn't see any answers of my question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to adapt the Reduce-part from the multmerge function for your issue.

```
#read in the data (can be replaced with filenames
#like f1 <- read.table(file, header=F)
#or even lapply(list.files(mypath), read.table, header=F) 
#to get all dataframes in a list
f1 <- read.table(text="5 A1
23 A3
1 B2
289 BX5
90 D3", header=F)

f2 <- read.table(text="2 A1
10 A2
3 B1
1 BX4
90 D3
24 E0", header=F)

f3 <- read.table(text="4 A0
11 A2
1 B1
2 D3", header=F)

#put files in list
myfiles <- list(f1,f2,f3)

#changing colnames because I like keeping my data in order/knowing where it came from.
myfiles <- lapply(1:length(myfiles),function(x){
  r <- myfiles[[x]]
  colnames(r) <- c(paste0("f",x),"ID")
  r
})

#using the Reduce-function
res <- Reduce(function(x,y) {merge(x,y,all=T, by="ID")}, myfiles)
res[is.na(res)]<-0
res

> res
    ID  f1 f2 f3
1   A1   5  2  0
2   A3  23  0  0
3   B2   1  0  0
4  BX5 289  0  0
5   D3  90 90  2
6   A2   0 10 11
7   B1   0  3  1
8  BX4   0  1  0
9   E0   0 24  0
10  A0   0  0  4
```

Comment: Thanks! It works as what I wanted. So, it seems that I was wrong from the beginning to use merge by row, while it is supposed to be merge by column, right?

Comment: Based on your provided input and output, you are merging by column.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with `dplyr`. First you need to load your data without assigning row names. Below, I reuse your file1,file2,file3 structures, but you might as well read them in the proper format like you did with df1,df2, df3. You need a Names column to join on. Then you do two consecutive `full_join`. I then sort the data and change NAs to 0.

```
file1 <-data.frame(Names=rownames(file1),V1=file1,row.names = NULL)
file2 <-data.frame(Names=rownames(file2),V1=file2,row.names = NULL)
file3 <-data.frame(Names=rownames(file3),V1=file3,row.names = NULL)

library(dplyr)
out <-file1  %>%
full_join(file2,by = "Names") %>%
full_join(file3,by = "Names") %>%
arrange(Names)
out[is.na(out)]<-0
#> out
#   Names V1.x V1.y V1
#1     A0    0    0  4
#2     A1    5    2  0
#3     A2    0   10 11
#4     A3   23    0  0
#5     B1    0    3  1
#6     B2    1    0  0
#7    BX4    0    1  0
#8    BX5  289    0  0
#9     D3   90   90  2
#10    E0    0   24  0
```

**Update**

To deal with an arbitrary number of files, we have to introduce a loop.

```
myfiles <- list(file1,file2,file3)
out <-file1                       #first file
for (i in myfiles[-1]){           #all but first file
out <-full_join(out,i,by = "Names")
}
out <-arrange(out,Names)
out[is.na(out)]<-0
out
> out
   Names V1.x V1.y V1
1     A0    0    0  4
2     A1    5    2  0
3     A2    0   10 11
4     A3   23    0  0
5     B1    0    3  1
6     B2    1    0  0
7    BX4    0    1  0
8    BX5  289    0  0
9     D3   90   90  2
10    E0    0   24  0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is this `%>%`? I couldn't find it by Googling. And how to do this for more than 3 files? We don't need to type full_join many times, right?

Comment: How would you generalize this to an arbitrary number of files?

Comment: @sentausa `%>%` is a forward-pipe operator from the `magrittr` package. `dplyr` imports this package.

Comment: @Heroka For an arbitrary numbre of files, you need a loop. See my updated answer